# Change GameObject's material during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime

I want to instantiate four new gameobject. And I want to assign four materials which are received from web server. Now, I can create four materials and store the images to them. But, I can't change the four gameobject material. For example, I want to change first gameobject material is image0, then second gameobject is image1, and so on. Anyone can help me? Here is my code:

```
public int k = 0;
public string filename;
public string url;
public string path;
public GameObject newpaper;
public Material material;
public GameObject newObject ;



[MenuItem("GameObject/Create Material")]

void Start () {
    StartCoroutine (LoadImage ());
}


void Update () {

    GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = material;


}

IEnumerator LoadImage(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        Instantiate (newpaper);

        filename = "image" + k.ToString () + ".png";
        Debug.Log (k);
        url = "https://wwwfoodparadisehk.000webhostapp.com/" + filename; 
        WWW www = new WWW (url);
        yield return www;

        path = "Assets/MyMaterial" + k.ToString () + ".mat";

        k = k + 1;

        material = new Material (Shader.Find ("Sprites/Default"));
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset (material, path);


        Debug.Log (AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (material));

        material.mainTexture = www.texture;

        //GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = material;
        yield return 0;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the new instance of `newpaper` and then set its material as follows -

```
public int k = 0;
public string filename;
public string url;
public string path;
public GameObject newpaper;
public Material material;
public Material planeMaterial;
public GameObject newObject ;

[MenuItem("GameObject/Create Material")]

void Start () {
    StartCoroutine (LoadImage ());
}


void Update () {

}

IEnumerator LoadImage(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        GameObject newPaperInstance = Instantiate (newpaper) as GameObject;

        filename = "image" + k.ToString () + ".png";
        Debug.Log (k);
        url = "https://wwwfoodparadisehk.000webhostapp.com/" + filename; 
        WWW www = new WWW (url);
        yield return www;

        path = "Assets/MyMaterial" + k.ToString () + ".mat";

        k = k + 1;

        material = new Material (Shader.Find ("Sprites/Default"));
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset (material, path);


        Debug.Log (AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (material));

        material.mainTexture = www.texture;

        newPaperInstance.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = material;

        // set newpaper's child "Plane"'s material
        newPaperInstance.transform.Find("Plane").gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = planeMaterial;
        //GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = material;
        yield return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: There is another question. gameobject newpaper has parent and it is Plane. I want to change the Plane material. How can I change it?

Comment: You can access a gameObject's parent using `newPaperInstance.transform.parent.gameObject` and then access it's `Renderer` component and change it's material. :)

Comment: Can you edit the code for me? I can't do it. I don't know the script is pasted correctly.

Comment: `newPaperInstance.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = PlaneMaterial;` Add this line wherever you want to set the `newpaper` material. Make sure to set `newPaperInstance`'s parent and `PlaneMaterial` contains the desired material.

Comment: I want to apologise for my mistakes. The instance newpaper is parent and plane is child. I want to change plane material. I am beginner , sorry!

Comment: Thankyou very very very much! I can change their material.

Comment: Hey I want to ask a question about receiving image from server. Now, I am using for loop to duplicate four newpaper. And I want to change it. If the server has received one image, then one newpaper will instance in Unity. If two images in server, instance two. The max no is four newpaper. How can I do that?